# Making Test(s) Fail if the `application-context` Encounters an Exception

Tags: java, spring, maven

When running `mvn clean install` against my Maven project, **Build Success** showed up.

However, running an individual test in IntelliJ showed that a test had failed since my `test-application-context` had encountered a `RuntimeException`.

Since this application-context failed to start the test environment, a few Maven tests did **not** run since they depended on the test-application-context to start up. But, even though these tests were skipped, **Build Success** still appeared.

I'd like Maven to fail those "skipped" tests if the application-context encounters a RuntimeException.

How can I configure the POM to show these tests as failures?

Comment: Could you provide some examples of where things go wrong e.g. a test that should fail. Also spring and junit versions may help to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Well, in the initialization step of my Spring + TestNG test, it threw an Exception because my Java code throws a RuntimeException is a particular database is empty. A few tests depended on executing the code that hits this database. Since an exception was thrown when setting up the environment, those tests never ran! I would've expected those dependent tests to have failed since they did not run.